# Why do we care about Bidual Spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, intuition, dual-spaces

I attach the definition of a bidual(double dual) space here:

[image]

I know that the canonical injection (i.e. the evaluation map) is what a general point in the bidual space should "do". However, what **"actual"** examples can we find that this bidual operator naturally appears? Why do we care about this space and where does it naturally arise?

Comment: Google "dual of Banach space".  The standard examples are the dual of $c_0$ being $\ell^1$, and the dual of $\ell^p$, ($1 \le p < \infty$), is $\ell^q$, where $\tfrac1p+\tfrac1q = 1$.

Comment: So that the bidual of $\ell^p$ if $1<p<\infty$ is $\ell^p$, and the bidual of $c_0$ is $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: What do you mean by an "actual" example? If $V$ is a vector space (over $\Bbb R$, to keep it simple), then $V^*$ is the space of all continuous linear functions from $V \to \Bbb R$. Likewise $V^{**}$ is the space of all continuous linear functions from $V^* \to \Bbb R$, and $V^{***}$ is the space of all continuous linear functions from $V^{**} \to \Bbb R$, etc. These are all well-defined constructions on $V$. It is not clear to me what you are after. One use of the bidual is that if $V$ is not complete, the evaluation map inserts $V$ in $V^{**}$ and you can use its closure to complete $V$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry of the confusion. I think what I was trying to ask is: why do we care about this space. Where would it naturally arise?

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner Look up reflexivity of a space.

Comment: One other reason for considering the bidual is what it can tell you about the original space. The evaluation map injects the original space into the bidual. When the original space is finite-dimensional or complete, it is an isomorphism. But otherwise the bidual is larger. How it is larger - in particular, the quotient of the bidual by the image of the evaluation map - tells you something about the topology of the original space.